# Mysql error:Unknown column 'variable' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this function that returns a constant..Here is my class and function:

```
class Backlinks extends GoogleSearch {
const ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW = 606;

    function robotsNoIndexNoFollow(){
    $crawler = new Connection();
    $curl = $crawler -> setUrl($this->url) ->getDocument();
    if ($curl){
        $html = new simple_html_dom($curl);
        $robots = $html -> find("meta[name=robots]", 0);
        $html -> clear();
        unset ($crawler);
        if ($robots){
            $content = $robots -> getAttribute("content");
            $content = strtolower($content);
            if (substr_count($content, "noindex")){
                return ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW; 
            }
            if (substr_count($content, "nofollow")){
                return ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem above is in the ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW contatnt.
The constant goes into another function as an error parameter to be updated in the database.

```
public function setStatus($error){
    $status = $error;
    if (!$error){
        $status = 200;
    }
    // only update the pages which weren't already scanned (for historic purposes).
    $query = "UPDATE task_pages tp 
        SET scan_status = $status 
        WHERE page_id = $this->pageID AND scan_status = 0";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I get two errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW - assumed
>   'ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW' in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\backlinks\cron\Backlinks.php on line 78
>   Unknown column 'ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW' in 'field list'

One is the problem with the constant not being defined..which I dont understand why.
The second problem is with the sql..which interprets the constant as a column?!?

Why and how to correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'self' to reference the constant:

return self::ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW

Otherwise, PHP would try to find the constant in the global scope even though in your case this is a class constant.

Comment: You should also consider returning `0` instead of `false` from your `robotsNoIndexNoFollow`, because passing false as `$error` would cause an error in your SQL code (I believe)

Comment: There's already a if(!$error) condition to take care of that I think

Answer (score 3):

You need qoutes around the string for MySQL to recognise it as data instead of a constant. Try:

```
"UPDATE task_pages tp 
        SET scan_status = '$status' 
        WHERE page_id = $this->pageID AND scan_status = 0";
```

Comment: I get both errors..again.This time the second error is different: Incorrect integer value: 'ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW' for column 'scan_status' at row 1

Comment: As one user mentioned below: 
"You need to use 'self' to reference the constant:
return self::ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW"

Comment: Also what data type is the scan_status field? is it varchar or integer?

Comment: Thats causing the "Incorrect integer value: ROBOTS_NOINDEX_NOFOLLOW' for column 'scan_status'" error. You cant store a String in a field that is of type integer.